# When using GeoPandas in Python, using the gdf.to_crs() method with the built-in gdf.crs method gives an innacurate transformation

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas, wgs84, lambert-conformal-conic

I am trying to use GeoPandas to run some coordinate transformations and I am getting an inaccurate transformation when using the to_crs() method. Here is the code sample:

```
import geopandas as gpd
gdf_clcc = gpd.read_file('test_CLCC.shp')
gdf_wgs84 = gpd.read_file('test_WGS84.shp')
gdf_conv = gdf_wgs84.to_crs(gdf_clcc.crs)
gdf_conv.to_file('test_conv.shp')
```

In my mind, test_CLCC.shp and test_conv.shp should plot in the exact same locations but they do not--they're about 50 ft off. gdf_clcc is in "Clarke_1866_Lambert_Conformal_Conic" and gdf_wgs84 is in "WGS 84". Doing the conversion in ArcMap results in points at the exact same location. The Clarke_1866_Lambert_Conformal_Conic seems to be the source of the problem here because converting between other coordinate/projection systems using the gdf.to_crs() method works just fine. Might be worth noting that when I open the .prj files for gdf_clcc and gdf_conv they are identical except for the units which are 'UNIT["Foot_US",0.3048006096012192]' and 'UNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219]' respectively. Any ideas?

Here is the result of gdf_clcc.crs:

[image: result of gdf_clcc.crs]

and here is the result of gdf_wgs84.crs:

[image: result of gdf_wgs84.crs]

Comment: Are you setting a custom geographic transformation in ArcMap? Clarke 1866 is an ellipsoid (spheroid), not a geographic CRS, so there are no transformations available for it. It's possible that Geopandas is setting a transformation by assuming Clarke 1866 is actually NAD27. It could be doing an ellipsoid-to-ellipsoid conversion. If the offset is directly north-south that could be what's happening

Comment: Agreed with @mkennedy that the issue is likely due to an ellipsoid-to-ellipsoid transform (Clarke 1866 - NAD 27) that pyproj is missing but ArcGIS does use.